# AppendChild doesn't work for parent element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append checkboxes to the parent elements of the hyperlinks (i.e. to paragraphs). For some reason it doesn't work. Why?

```
<p><a href="https://example.com">Hyperlink</a></p>
<p><a href="https://example.org">Hyperlink</a></p>

<script>
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var input  = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

        // links[i].appendChild(input); // works
        links[i].parentElement.nodeName.appendChild(input); // doesn't work
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Replace `parentElement.nodeName` with `parentNode`.

Comment: @OriDrori Yes, exactly. It resolves the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

  // links[i].appendChild(input); // works
  // doesn't work - links[i].parentElement.nodeName.appendChild is not a function"
  // links[i].parentElement.nodeName.appendChild(input); 
  links[i].parentNode.appendChild(input);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p><a href="https://example.com">Hyperlink</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://example.org">Hyperlink</a></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<p><a href="https://example.com">Hyperlink</a></p>
<p>  <a href="https://example.org">Hyperlink</a></p>

<script>
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var input  = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        links[i].parentNode.appendChild(input);
    }
```

Comment: I think it is better to explain what changes are made rather than posting a block of code and say "try this"

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Will take that into consideration for my future answers